How are rockets able to keep their centers of mass in line with thrusters?
How can the thrusters of a rocket keep in line with its center of mass seemingly perfectly to not exert any torque and rotate the rocket? For torque to not be exerted, the force vector must align with the center of mass, but how can space companies like NASA and SpaceX ensure that this is true? In rocket launches, precision is vital for the success of the ship, and I feel as even small misalignments in the center of mass from an object an astronaut took with them would cause imprecisions.

how early of launches are you talking about in your second paragraph?  V-1 and V-2 had control in the 1940s.

Alex, "I believe" can usually be remediated with a quick google, and is normally not a good thing to have in an SE question. While your headline is a good question, you'd have been better leaving out that final paragraph

You seem to think that the centre of mass is something that needs to be measured precisely but that’s not required (and it moves continuously and substantially anyway, as fuel is consumed). The closed feedback systems work by measuring change in orientation and then correcting that continuously. It is orientation that needs to be measured precisely – centre of mass doesn’t come into it, although the end result will naturally be that thrust direction is closely aligned through it.

Answer: Practice, practice, practice, just like how you get to Carnegie Hall.

Gimballed engines, or other steering methods (vernier thrusters, fuel injection into nozzle, gimballed nozzle, RCS thrusters, differential thrust control), and a broad array of sensors measuring the current flight path and attitude (direction) of the rocket - gyroscopes, radio connection using phase shift to measure distance from (known) ground stations to centimeter precision, accelerometers, sun and star trackers, and many more, plus some pretty good controllers that process the sensor data and generate control signals for the gimbals (or whatever other means of control) - ensure the engines face just the right way, be it thrust through CoM, or thrust producing the correct momentum to correct for any error that was detected.
It's not that it's all perfect at all times, built to have zero error - but all errors are immediately, actively corrected, compensated for.
In early launches, passive stabilization was helpful - spin providing moment of inertia that would require significant forces to overcome, passive aerodynamic stabilization - shape and mass distribution that kept the orientation mostly constant - but even the ancient Nazi V2 rocket had a gyroscope and control surfaces on its fins, plus a very primitive analog "computer" (a shaped disk spun slowly that would push a potentiometer to different depths) to provide control over attitude.
